# How to put lable in ReachUI that moves along the slider in React

Tags: reactjs, slider

I am using ReachUI range slider 'https://reacttraining.com/reach-ui/slider'.

I am using this because it is giving me an option 
`<SliderMarker value={50} />`
This helps to put mark on a line where I need.

The only problem I am facing with this library is: I am not able to put a label of value that moves along the slider.
And even if its possible in this then I am not able to understand it from its documentation.

Is it possible in this library to put label?

Or is there any good React library for the range slider that can fulfill my these two requirements of: **mark on a certain value of slider** and **movable label**.

please suggest !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple. The code for reachUI slider looks like this:

```
<Slider name="coldRent"                    
                min={}
                max={}
                step={}
                value={}
                onChange={}                    
              >
    <SliderTrack>
      <SliderTrackHighlight />                        
      <SliderMarker value={} />
      <SliderHandle>
         <span> </span>
      </SliderHandle>
    </SliderTrack>
</Slider>
```

Just add the span between sliderHandle and you are done.